# How to resize images in % of their size with grunt?

Tags: gruntjs, imagemagick

How to resize images to a multiple of their original size using grunt ?

I have a folder with original images within a tree structure

- GFX\myDirectoryTree\Files.png

I want it to export resized files to several tree structures

- OUTPUT\100\myDirectoryTree\Files.png > 100% size
- OUTPUT\50\myDirectoryTree\Files.png > 50% size
- OUTPUT\20\myDirectoryTree\Files.png > 20% size

Comment: maybe this will help? https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-image-resize

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a gruntfile.js task for the grunt-image-resize Node package mentioned by bencripps.

```
image_resize: {
      resize_50: {
        options: {
          width: '50%',
          quality: 1,
          overwrite: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'GFX/myDirectoryTree',
          src: ['{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png}'],
          dest: 'OUTPUT/50/myDirectoryTree',
        }]
      },
      resize_20: {
        options: {
          width: '20%',
          quality: 1,
          overwrite: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'GFX/myDirectoryTree',
          src: ['{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png}'],
          dest: 'OUTPUT/20/myDirectoryTree',
        }]
      }2
   },
```